# \tcblisting uses alphanumerical foonote instead of numerical?

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox

Why is `\tbclisting` using alphanumerical notation of footnotes instead of numerical?

```
\documentclass{article}
\parskip\baselineskip

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tcblisting}{before lower={\vspace{-1em}\parskip\baselineskip}}
This is a \footnote{footnote}
\end{tcblisting}

This is a \footnote{footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: LaTeX is so strange... Why would anyone ever think about `\thempfootnote` being the one to redefine for minipages?

Comment: You can read it like this: `\the m[ini] p[age] footnote`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Yes, but only once you know it you can make any sense of it... Thanks for the hint!